# How can I bind Win+Space to run Launchy in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, boot-camp, hotkeys, launchy

I have Windows 10 dual-booting with macOS on a Macbook Pro. When it's running Windows, I want the Win+Space key combination to open [Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/), like it used to back in Windows 7 - mainly 'cos this is the same combination used to run Spotlight on macOS and so it'll give me a far more consistent experience between the two operating systems.

The problem is that when I try to bind Win+Space in Launchy, I get an error "The hotkey Meta+Space is already in use, please select another" - which I'm guessing is because on Windows 10, Win+Space is a built-in hotkey for switching keyboard layouts. I can't find any way to unbind it. I've found a couple of [registry modifications](http://www.ghacks.net/2015/03/22/how-to-disable-specific-global-hotkeys-in-windows/) that have worked successfully for unbinding other Win+X key combinations - so I've managed to disable Win+E for Explorer and Win+M for Minimize all Windows, just to check it works - but I can't work out how to disable Win+Space. I've tried putting a literal space into the registry key, and I've seen a couple of posts saying you need to right-click the registry key to edit the binary data and enter the appropriate [virtual key code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx) - which would be 0x20 or `20 00` for Space, if I understand it correctly? - but I can't get this to work either. I'm not sure whether I'm trying to do something impossible or I just can't get the syntax quite right - any ideas?

Comment: If you have no other keyboard layouts you can use Win+Space

Comment: @Ramhound doesn't appear so - Launch still reports Win+Space is already in use even if I only have a single keyboard layout installed.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of old but in the Local Group Policy Editor you can disable all windows hot keys. The steps are

- Open Local Group Policy Editor
- Expand User Configuration/Windows Components then double click on file explorer
- Scroll all the way down, then open up disable windows hotkey

I still can't find a way to disable just win space bar, so this will have to do. I use win + l too much to justify it, but I hope it works for you!

Answer (score 0):

I happen to be using Flow Launcher, but have the same problem.  I just:

1. Configured Flow Launcher to use "Win+Alt+Space" instead.
2. Installed Microsoft [PowerToys](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys)
3. Used PowerToys to map "Win+Space" to "Win+Alt+Space"

[image: screenshot of PowerToys' Keyboard Manager]

Flow Launcher cannot directly use the "Win+Space" hotkey, but PowerToys can, and can remap it to the alternate which activates Flow Launcher.  The same should work for any program that wants to use a hotkey/shortcut that PowerToys can remap.